# Diferencias entre crear un elemento desde cero o tenerlo almacenado en una variable

Tags: javascript

Cuál es la diferencia de un elemento ya 'creado' almacenado en una variable o crearlo desde cero

```js
var box = document.getElementById("set");
var bc1 = document.getElementById("bc1");

bc1.onclick = function() {
var div1 = "<div class='caja1'>Hola</div>";
box.innerHTML = div1;
}


// ELEMENTO CREADO DESDE CERO
var bc2 = document.getElementById("bc2");

bc2.onclick = function() {
var crear = document.createElement("div");
crear.innerHTML = "Hola 2";
crear.setAttribute("class", "caja2");

box.appendChild(crear);
}
```

```html
<div id="set"></div>
<button id="bc1">Crear 1</button>
<button id="bc2">Crear 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como lo tienes, en la primera opción remplazas el contenido del div y solo queda ese elemento; mientras la segunda opción te permite agregar tantos elementos como necesites, aunque se puede tener la misma funcionalidad con ambos.

En teoría, agregar elementos con `innerHTML` es más lento, porque el navegador debe interpretar la cadena para crear objetos e insertarlos y `appendChild()` trabaja directamente con objetos.

Conclusión: Si solo vas a remplazar el contenido del div, no importa qué uses, pero si vas a trabajar con múltiples elementos, definitivamente conviene `appendChild()` que te permite mayor flexibilidad, como asignar atributos de manera más sencilla, como ejemplo:

```js
var box = document.getElementById("set");
var bc2 = document.getElementById("bc2");
// Crear un contador
var cuenta = 0;

bc2.onclick = function() {
    // Incrementar contador
    cuenta ++;
    var crear = document.createElement("div");
    crear.innerHTML = "Hola " + cuenta; // Contar mensajes
    crear.setAttribute("class", "caja2");

    box.appendChild(crear);
}
```

```html
<div id="set"></div>
<button id="bc2">Crear y contar</button>
```